# Software to help place ICs on a wirewrap prototype board

Tags: integrated-circuit, layout

I have a moderately complex circuit (about 80 LSTTL Chips - a bit retro), designed and working in Logisim. I have 2 Augat WireWrap prototype boards (Similar to the image below) that I want to use to build the working circuit.

Does anyone know of any software which would allow me to play around with different placements of the various (16 and 24 pin) DIP chips on a "virtual" prototype board, before I commit to the first wirewrap?

I have looked at Fritzing, but I am not really planning on using a breadboard.

I plan to learn kCad, to draw up some circuit diagrams as a checklist when I am wrapping. Does that allow layout on such a board?
[image]

Comment: Realistically there is no sane reason to build such a thing!   If you had the design in a PCB package, the "ratsnest" view might be interesting for comparing placement strategies, especially what's left after defining power pours to get that out of the picture.

Comment: What do you mean by "play around with different placements"?  What are you trying to optimize?  BTW, I've used those same WW boards in the past.  We always went straight from a schematic/netlist to the wrapped board, once we defined the geometry and parts placement for the WW machine to use.  I don't think we ever iterated the layout, except as part of a pre-placement review with SMEs.

Comment: @Chris You're probably correct. Especially given that it's a 95% Compatible 6502 Clone, made from SSI TTL Chips. But I've always wanted to do it, and I intend to see it through to completion. At which point it will be connected to my lovely old ADM5 Terminal. Sometimes it's the journey Chris :-)

Comment: Oh, one more thing.  What speed to hope to run this at?  10 MHz, probably doable.  30 MHz or higher, probably not.  Speaking from experience here.

Comment: @SteveSh Well, for example, I know that I can get the 4 Microcode EEPROMS , the instruction decoder circuit, and the ALU on one board. But I'mjust doing this for fun, so I wanted to leave myself some space between chips to make debugging easier. So I really just wanted some electronic graph paper, on which I could place all of the little rectangular packages. I think maybe this is not the place for a hobbyist designer to bring steampunk questions. I am hand-wrapping this btw.

Comment: @SteveSh 1 MHz, same as the Apple II, my first computer

Comment: Anything approaching 1cm/ns risetime can be done with twisted magnet wire to eliminate ringing.  Layout software is less important than manually routing ratsnest for shortest clock path length to minimize 10nH/cm inductance. But again twisted magnet wire or coax for analog sensitive cats can work ok.  Get red+green coated magnet wire or the standard pvc for non critical stuff

Comment: @TonyStewartSunnyskyguyEE75 Ah, I think I used the term "Layout" incorrectly here. All I meant was that I would like some visual aid to allow me to "place" the chips at different locations on the board, in order to space them out, but get some kind of semi-optimal arrangement, before I start to manually insert the chips into place, and begin wrapping. Maybe I just need to do something in Powerpoint, with a grid and some shapes - I just though there might be something out there, but I guess this stuff went out with the ark, if it was ever done manually at all.

Comment: Excel spreadsheeet works well with objects that have scalable dimensions. Signals with 30AWG and power with 24AWG to 26 if possible and avoid daisy chain to break the links, if there is any significant power and 1cap per IC. But I understood what you meant.. and avoid crosstalk and use twisted pairs for critical timing

Comment: For doing rough layouts, when I don't want to dive into Mentor Graphics, I just use MS Visio.  I've created a Visio stencil of part outlines that I use a lot and just lay them down on a to-scale representation of the board.

Comment: Scratch the 24AWG, I see you have fat power traces

Comment: @TonyStewartSunnyskyguyEE75 Thank you Tony. I have plenty of 30AWG, I will get some 24AWG for the power. I have all the caps for the ICs. Can you tell me what you mean by "Avoid daisy chain..." ?

Comment: Those boards had planes on the top and bottom.  One was used for GND (the top one, IIRC), and the other for VCC.  You could buy small clips (looked like very small safety pin) that would allow to connect and VCC and GND pin of a part directly to the appropriate place.  They had to be soldered into place.

Comment: Wow, does that bring back memories of trying to find the bad wrap, unwrapping top wraps to get to the bottom ones, debugging clock bounce and crosstalk and of course hours spent doing the wrapping.  I'd just go get a PCB made, it's so inexpensive these days and would save many hours.

Comment: I once inherited a design of a backplane with aircraft quality bundled WW.I had to break the news to the tech to rip up and go spider web spaced or rat’s nest.  R/G twisted pair works very well to reduce crosstalk and ringing. 1 twist/“ nominal unless you want lower impedance then more.

Answer (score 1):

A long, long time ago I would outsource wire-wrap to a local service. They would take my netlist and break it up into 'levels'.

That is, their software would parse my netlist into 2-point nets. Larger nets would get wired up on a second 'level' (2 wraps on the same post). The benefit of this approach was it made the wiring neater, and also make it easier to make changes later.

Probably you could do this with some kind of script, sorting on the chip x-y placement on the board.

As far as visualizing this... I've not seen a tool that does that for wire-wrap.

Comment: I think either way it's going to be a labor of love :)

Comment: @crassic Exactly, and an exercise in nostalagia.